# Replacing all occurrences of a substring in a string in an SQL column except first occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string in a a column text as like below :

```
Test:HJ,BHS,Test:FG,SKL,Test:KL,PDC
```

( and so on ...there is no fixed length of this string )

each time Test appears it is followed by Two letters,Three letters (  this is the patter of the string )

Now I want to Replace this string with Test appearing only once like below:

```
Test:HJ,BHS,:FG,SKL,:KL,PDC
```

Comment: You are almost definitely going to need to write a UDF to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `replace` like this

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(500) = 'Test:HJ,BHS,Test:FG,SKL,Test:KL,PDC  ( and so on ...there is no fixed length of this string )'

SELECT Replace(@Text, ',' + LEFT(@Text,charindex(':', @Text)), ',:')
```

Returns

```
Test:HJ,BHS,:FG,SKL,:KL,PDC  ( and so on ...there is no fixed length of this string )
```

Comment: `SELECT Replace(@Text, ',Test:', ',:')` would have been a bit simpler, but your answer has the bonus that it will still work if the target string changes.